# Transferring large number of files from one server to another

Tags: ssh, cpanel

I am moving servers and our images directory has around 15,000 images (2GB in size) which needs to be moved on to new server.

Images will have a different path on new server so can't just migrate whole CPANEL.

Any easy way to resolve this issue?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: du you have SSH access of the old server?

Comment: I have SSH access to both servers

Answer (score 1):

use SFTP from one server to the other 
http://support.cs.utah.edu/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=33&Itemid=59

edit: In answer to yr question below:
Don't need local download, sftp is direct server to server. Use sftp from SSH shell on source server like so

```
$ cd source_directory
$ sftp user@otherserver
Password:
Connected to otherserver
sftp> cd target_directory  //this is changing dir on remote server not local
sftp> put filename
```

or for all files from source dir to target dir

sftp> put *

Comment: Thanks - is there a way to use SFTP via some software? But I don't want files to first download on local computer.

Comment: I added extra how to above. sftp will prompt for password for other server. Try a couple of files to get comfortable before you do wildcard. good luck! BTW the // is a comment don't put it in.

Comment: once at the sftp> prompt you need to use lcd to change directory locally  since !cd doesn't work. Most other commands work locally from the sftp> prompt of you put ! in fromt of them.  For instance you can check where you are locally using !pwd at the sftp> prompt. Enjoy!