# file_put_contents is unable to get whole file

Tags: php, hostmonster

I am using hostmonster as hosting provider.

I have written below code.

```
$mp4_url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4';
$filename = 'sample.mp4';

file_put_contents( $filename , fopen($mp4_url, 'r' ) );
```

I am seeing strange behaviour. Sometimes it works but sometimes it copies only few bites like sometimes size of file is 100kb sometimes 600kb sometimes it copies whole file.

Please suggest what should I do to copy any mp4 file from any server to our server.

We have to copy large files, size can be 600MB or 1GB.

Comment: what are you trying to do actually?

Comment: file_get_content() function is used to get the content from another site

Comment: I am trying to copy mp4 file from another website to my server.

Comment: its a very ill defined code without any error checking etc and you can try binary mode using b flag.Anyway it doesn't seem like an efficient way of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @rahultyagi what shold I do?

Comment: does hostmonster provides ssh terminal access ? if yes this might help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443458/transferring-large-number-of-files-from-one-server-to-another) otherwise go with the answers below

Answer (score 2):

Try [`copy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php). This will do your job:

```
$file = 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4';
$newfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/sample.mp4';

if ( copy($file, $newfile) ) {
    echo "Copy success!";
}else{
    echo "Copy failed.";
}
```

Comment: Can you pease let me know what it will do and why my previous code is not working?

Comment: @RakeshKanyal just replace your pervious code with this one

Comment: I triend in my local. it was working fine. on live after few seconds I am getting blank page.

Comment: @RakeshKanyal restart local server and try

Answer (score 1):

use curl rather than using `file_put_contents`

```
$url='http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4';
$saveto='path';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
$raw = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if (file_exists($saveto)) {
    unlink($saveto);
}
$fp = fopen($saveto, 'x');
fwrite($fp, $raw);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Can you pease let me know what it will do and why my previous code is not working?